# How to grep for "U+2028"?

Tags: git, unicode, diff

*git diff* is showing me there have been a few of these in my code:

```
                     <div style={styles.loadingContainer}><U+2028>
                         <CircularProgress />
-                    </div><U+2028>
+                    </div>
```

I would like to grep all files to find and remove these. They were screwing up the design and costing me like 3 hours so far :-(

Comment: Downvoting without commenting sucks!

Comment: you want a find and replace for the files inside your whole project right? Why don't you try with your IDE? what is the IDE you are using?

Comment: vim (ignore this text)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using bash you can use its string substitution

```
grep $'\u2028' /path/to/file
```

Other shells may have similar features.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. `git diff`shows: <U+2028> but grep doesn't produce any output. Vim shows me there is a character before the line break. If I delete that character, git diff doesn't show <U+2028> anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` is showing the unicode character 2028 (i.e. *LINE SEPARATOR*, see eg. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) as `<U+2028>`.

To find all places where this unicode character is used, run:

```
git grep "$(printf '\u2028')"
```

This uses the command `printf` to produce the requested unicode char, which is then passed to `git grep` as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to your project directory with terminal.
- `grep -nr U+2028`

For your objective **Search & Replace path** option in your IDE would help. For intelliJ you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: greps successfully the string "U+2028" but not the unicode character itself.